# Idea's cmd and git bash don't see mvn command

Tags: maven, jetbrains-ide

Idea's cmd and git bash don't see mvn command.
If I run this out of Idea it works:

[image]

But in Idea's CMD or Bash I see "mvn: command not found"

[image]

Why this happens? I set path to C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin.
On Linux it works well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

these are issue with maven path configuration into your system. try to reconfigure the maven, you can also refer this link to configure.

https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Comment: in addition to this, I had to add MAVEN_HOME/bin to the path.

Answer (score 0):

Set path as below

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin:/c/Program\ Files/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin
```